# How to send a array as a parameter to a web service using SOAP and objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, soap, parameters

I'm working in a iPhone app that needs to send a array as a parameter using SOAP.
this is the current request and connection:

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
     "<soap:Body>\n"
     "<function xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" />\n"
     "</soap:Body>\n"
     "</soap:Envelope>\n"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myHost.com/myWebService/service.asmx"]; //the url to the WSDL

        NsMutableURLRequest theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
     NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMessage length]];

     [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
     [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Lenght"];
     [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
     [theRequest addValue:@"myhost.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
     [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/function" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
     [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Now, to send parameters I looked at the WSDL of the function description for the input is like this:

```
    <s:complexType name="ArrayOfDictionaryEntry">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DictionaryEntry" type="tns:DictionaryEntry" />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
          <s:complexType name="DictionaryEntry">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Key" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Value" />
            </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>

<s:element name="functionInput">
        <s:complexType />
      </s:element>
```

I guess then that I need to make a array of dictionary entries.
what I would like to send is something like this

```
[ location => USA, 
  module => DEVELOPMENT]
```

But I'm kind of confused.

- the array is created outside the
  SOAP, like an NSArray or inside the
  SoapMessage?
- if so... How is it done?
- and the DictionaryEntry, should I
  make a class?

thanks for your time n.n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your xml needs to look like this :-

```
 <ArrayOfDictionaryEntry>
      <DictionaryEntry>
         <key>key1</key>
         <value>val1</value>
      </DictionaryEntry>
      <DictionaryEntry>
          <key>key2</key>
          <value>val2</value>
       </DictionaryEntry>
   <ArrayOfDictionaryEntry>
```

I would create a NSMutableDictionary object  with all the key value pairs and then iterate through them and build the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you... I finally connected with the web service sending the parameters...
It looks like that the person responsible of configuring the web service didn't actually made the changes so i could send the parameters..

The WSDL now looks like this:

```
 <s:element name="GetMonitorList">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="location" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="moduleName" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
```

And my code looks like this:

```
@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
    "<soap:Body>\n"
     "<function xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
    "<location>USA</location>"
    "<moduleName>DEVELOPMENT</moduleName>"
    "</function>"
    "</soap:Body>\n"
    "</soap:Envelope>\n"
```